# Cyclic include, not valid error while creating fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a fragment to display a map. I have done someting like this:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   />
```

But in the graphical layout, I can see the following error:-

[image]

When I right click and choose the fragment layout I further see the following error:-

[image]

how can I resolve the following error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put your main activity layout as a fragment inside your main activity layout. That's what the "cyclic include" error means.

You don't seem to have a fragment layout readily available. You can click on the "New Layout..." button to create a new one.